# How do I implement a custom theme function?

Tags: 8, theming

I'm trying to print a markup in a peg. I've implemented a function passed the values through the variables. Also I've implemented a custom theme function with a markup.

But it is giving the error.

> Template "modules/custom/example/templates/example.html.twig" is not defined (Drupal\Core\Template\Loader\ThemeRegistryLoader: Unable to find template "modules/custom/example/templates/example.html.twig" in the Drupal theme registry.).

Here is my code.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function example_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
   return array(
    'example' => array(
      'variables' => array('items' => array()),
    ),
  );
}
// Theme function
function theme_example($variables) {
   return 'hi'
}
// Preprocess implementation.
function template_preprocess_example(&$variables) {
  $value = 'hi how are you';
  return $value;
}
```

I've implemented both one after another, but they didn't work. Is the custom theme function format changed in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description of valid parameters in [the docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8):

> **function**: (deprecated in Drupal 8.0.x, will be removed in Drupal 9.0.x) If specified, this will be the function name to invoke for this implementation. If neither 'template' nor 'function' are specified, a default template name will be assumed. See above for more details.

So if you must use a function, you need to be explicit:

```
function example_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
   return array(
    'example' => array(
      'variables' => array('items' => array()),
      'function' => 'theme_example',
    ),
  );
}
```

But considering that method is deprecated in favour of template files, it would be better to use one. You can do so by simply creating a template file at modules/custom/example/templates/example.html.twig